# Android - Check if a file exists just using a part of its name

Tags: android

I have car models that each model can contain one or more images. So I have named my images using this protocol: CarModel_id_Image_id
where id is an unique number identifier.

I wonder if I could ask if "CarModel_id" exist?

here is some of my code:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/MyApp/Images/CarModel_" + id +"_");
if (f.exists()){
      /** some code here **/
}
```

Is there a way to do what I want? Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: Is there a way to do what I want?  Yes it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get all files in your directory, loop through them, and check if the id exists in the file names

```
   File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/MyApp/Images/");

   File[] files = f.listFiles();

    for (File file : files) {
                 //check if file name contains model number here using contains
                 //or split the string on underscore and check the id index
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8752412/1099716 You can also filter files passing FileFilter

Comment: @AccessDenied same basic idea, didn't realize there was a FileFilter class for list files. Kind of a nice thing to know so thanks for that! That would get you all files with that model number maybe that is what is wanted? Question was pretty vague

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void writeToFile(String directory, String fileName,String fileNameNew, String data ) {   
File out = null;
OutputStreamWriter outStreamWriter = null;
FileOutputStream outStream = null;    
String LOG_DIR = "/MyLogFolder";
directory += LOG_DIR;
File dir = new File(directory);
out = new File(new File(directory), fileNameNew);

File f = new File(new File(directory).getPath());

    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    boolean existFile = false;

if (dir.exists()) {
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.getName().contains(fileName)) {
                existFile = true;
                file.renameTo(out);
            }
        }
    }

if(!existFile) {
        try {
            out.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(out,true);
        outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        assert outStreamWriter != null;
        outStreamWriter.append(data);
        outStreamWriter.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
try {
        assert outStreamWriter != null;
        outStreamWriter.append(data);
        outStreamWriter.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and for call:

```
String date = Calendar.ShortDate.replace("/","-");
String time = Calendar.time.hours.toString() + "." + Calendar.time.minutes.toString();
Logger.writeToFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString(),"MyLog","MyLog"+" "+date+" "+time+".txt","\n\n-------------\n"+"YourText");
```