# Check if folder exists using a numeric wildcard including decimals

Tags: java, directory, wildcard, exists

I'm trying to write code that checks whether the Acrobat xx.x folder is present on a user's PC, where `xx.x` represents a potential Acrobat version number, such as Acrobat 10.0 or Acrobat 11.1. **Meaning I do not know what xx.x will be**. The answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752034/how-to-check-a-file-if-exists-with-wildcard-in-java) seems to assume I know what value the wildcard takes, but I don't in my case.

The purpose is to eventually write .js files into the directory `...\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat xx.x\Acrobat\Javascripts`

So far I identify whether 32/64-bit OS is installed and set the Program Files path into `progFiles`. Assuming that Adobe is installed, I then need to use this path in order to determine whether Acrobat xx.x is a subfolder such as:

```
folderToFind = new File(progFiles + "\\Adobe\\"+"\\Acrobat 11.1");
```

where `11.1` may take the form of any number from 0.1 to 99.9. I then can identify its existence with:

```
if (folderToFind.exists())
  {
    System.out.println("Acrobat folder found");
  }
```

An obvious approach is to create a loop, checking whether each and every possibility exists. This seems redundant and unnecessary. I'm hoping there's a more efficient approach such as:

```
  if (progFiles + "\\Adobe\\"+"\\Acrobat **.*\\Acrobat\\Javascripts".exists()){
 // ...
     }
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: [This SO post might answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752034/how-to-check-a-file-if-exists-with-wildcard-in-java)

Comment: I've read that already and it seems to assume that I know what `XXX` will be... but in my case I'm looking for a dynamic number from 0.1 to 99.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a [FileFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html)

And look for Files that match your description:
**Acrobat \d{1,2}\.\d**

Example:

```
    File dir = new File(path);
    File[] matchingFiles = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            String regex = "Acrobat \\d{1,2}\\.\\d";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(pathname.getName());
            return m.matches();
        }
    });
    for(File f : matchingFiles) {
        System.out.println(f.getName());
    }
```

You have complete control on how to build your Pattern

Comment: This looks promising, I'll test very soon and report back. Thanks

Comment: Works perfectly, I'll be sure to study it. Thank you very much